Base and emitter pins of BJT swapped
The Base and emitter pins of my BJT is as shown below.
But I need a BJT with Base and emitter pins swapped(1 and 2 swapped) as i have made a mistake in my schematic symbol creation. My PCB is already manufactured.
I have not found any part numbers in SOT-23 package yet with pin-1 as emitter and pin-2 as base.
Please suggest how can i resolve this issue?


They don't appear to exist as standard products. In the bad old days, TO-92 packaged transistors were made in many different pinouts, fortunately that's been standardized now, and even can be compatible between MOSFETs and BJTs. Your choices are likely between hacking in a standard part (perhaps get 2 of 3 by canting the part then add a jumper wire- which is then tacked down with UV adhesive, or try to flip it - not easy), re-spin the board, or make an adapter board (problematic for a part that small, but if you have $$$ multilayer boards perhaps practical).

If I understood your problem properly, you have in your PCB pins 2 and 1 swapped, like this, but the BJT is as the diagram in your question shows:

In that case, I would try to un-solder the BJT and re-solder it upside down, thus making pin 2 be the upper most pin, and pin 1 be the bottom most pin.
This takes some time and some very delicate and careful soldering.

Are you saying that the asker should flip the part over so that the top side rests against the board and the leads are hanging in the air, and then use solder to bridge the vertical gap between the pads and the leads?

@SophieSwett yes that's what I am suggesting. It is not an elegant solution but if the asker is prototyping something, it might just work. I have done it before.
Obviously it doesn't apply if this is for a production stage. In that case, he/she might have to re-design and re-manufacture the whole PCB, as the error is quite critical.
